# I'm getting a 42000 sql syntax error in netbeans but the same query string works fine in mysql console

Tags: java, mysql

Ok...here's my code and I don't understand where i'm going wrong...I'm getting a 42000 error in netbeans which i understand is an sql syntax error but it works perfectly fine in the mysql console

```
 try
     {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

         Connection CC =         
         DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pulsedb", "root", "carrizo");


String q1 = String.valueOf(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()); 
         String ans1 = jTextField9.getText();

         String q2 = String.valueOf(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
         String ans2 = jTextField10.getText();

         String recovQA  = "INSERT INTO pulsedb.mstuffrecovery (recov_qsn,recov_ans)     VALUES('"+q1+"',"+ans1+"')";
         String recovQA2  = "INSERT INTO pulsedb.mstuffrecovery2 (recov_qsn2,recov_ans2) VALUES('"+q2+"',"+ans2+"')";


         PreparedStatement PQS = CC.prepareStatement(recovQA);
         PreparedStatement PQQ = CC.prepareStatement(recovQA2);


         PQS.executeUpdate(recovQA);
         PQQ.executeUpdate(recovQA2);


catch(SQLException e)
             {

                 System.out.println(e.getSQLState());
                 e.getMessage();
                 e.getErrorCode();
                 e.printStackTrace();

             }
```

Comment: When you go to the doctor, do you tell them what is wrong with you? Or do you let them guess?

Comment: before ans1 and ans2 you are missing a '. You did it properly for q1 and q2.

On that note... +1 to Sotirios for being my comic relief of the day.

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @ TheOneWhoPrograms....Thanks a lot...kind of stupid but sometimes hard to detect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I doubt very much that the same query works in SQL console because you are missing a single quote (at least) and it would through an error. If you missed it, that means you are **not** running the same queries in console and in your code...
2) you should always use parameters when passing values to your SQL

Comment: I was typing them seperately that's which is probably why I missed that quote but works fine now..Thanks. On point 2) Can you give me a sample code...i'm not that good in programming yet

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html  
Your SQL will be 
`INSERT INTO tableName (fld1, fld2...)     VALUES(?, ?...)`